# private variable of an object without default constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class called Person with no default constructor :

```
class Person{
public:
    Person(std::string name); 
}
```

and a class usingPerson within which I want an object person as an attribute:

```
class usingPerson{
public:
    someMethod();


private:
    Person p1;
```

this gives me the error : class person has no default constructor.

I know this seems basic but I'm new to programming so can you tell me how do I initialise it with a name.

Comment: Note that the access specifier such as `private` is irrelevant to this error.

Comment: Ah. The member initializer list. The ratio of its importance to the language to the frequency with which it is taught is almost infinity.

Comment: You'll need to initialize it in the constructor or inline, with the name that it should be initialized with.